# Columns and rows (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my code,

```
select concat(month(b.delivery_date), "/", year(b.delivery_date)) as month_year, b.company, sum(b.subtotal) as revenue 
from all_company a, all_order_summary b 
where a.company_id = b.company_id and a.paid = 1 and year(b.delivery_date) = 2017 
group by year(b.delivery_date), month(b.delivery_date)
```

This prints something like this:

month_year|Company|Revenue

| 01/2017 | ABC123 | 500000

| 02/2017 | ABC123 | 100000

| 01/2017 | DEF456 | 300000

| 02/2017 | DEF456 | 800000

I want it to print this way,

[ space ] 01/2017 | 02/2017

ABC123 | 500000 | 100000 |

DEF456 | 300000 | 800000 |

What can I do to change this? (I'm relatively new to SQL)

Comment: Have you tried PIVOT??

Answer (score 0):

By using PIVOT we can achieve this. 
Below mentioned query gives you the result you desired:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
      Revenue, company, month_year
    FROM companies
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Revenue)
    FOR month_year IN ([01/2017], [02/2017])
)AS pvt
```

I have mentioned that table name as 'companies', modify it based on your actual table name

Comment: Those dates were just examples, my table will change based on a selected range of dates

Comment: You will need to include the whole range like  "FOR month_year IN ([01/2017], [02/2017].......[12/2017],)". Does your date range or data contains date/months from different years??

Comment: Hmm, yes, it would have a selected range of any years in the database. So, next year, it would have 2018.